# Global variable during recursion

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, anagram

---

I have a global variable masterList, which is a HashMap.

```
private static HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer> masterList = 
     new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer>();
```

I have a recursive function, generateAnagram that puts ArrayLists of anagrams in this HashMap with the number of words in the list as the value. However, the HashMap starts to mess up after the first call,and previous ArrayLists are overriden with the new one I'm trying to add, but the previous value remains. This results in two keys with the same value.
Here's a screenshot of the results - Click [here] http://tinypic.com/r/ka1gli/8

```
    private static void generateAnagram(Set<String> subsets, ArrayList<String> currList, letterMap wordMap) {
            if (wordMap.count() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Adding: " + currList);
                masterList.put(currList, currList.size());
                System.out.println("Current Master: " + masterList.toString());
            } else {
                for (String word : subsets) {
                    if (word.length() <= wordMap.count() && wordMap.isConstructionPossible(word)) {
                        //System.out.println("Word: " + word + "    "  + wordMap.isConstructionPossible(word));
                        wordMap.remove(word);
                        currList.add(word);
                        generateAnagram(subsets, currList, wordMap);
                        currList.remove(word);
                        wordMap.addBack(word);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: why not use a new arrayList whenever you do a recursion? If i m not wrong, i guess you are facing this issue since arrayList overrides the same memory location and that is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at this from the point of view of the parameters. The `ArrayList` reference is passed as an argument to your recursion call each time, but it still points to the same `ArrayList`. When you then put it into the hashmap, you are storing multiple references to the same, single, original `ArrayList`.

Therefore use [`ArrayList.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()) before adding it to the master list. Better still, store an immutable collection to ensure your hash doesn't get messed up in the HashMap:

```
HashMap<List<String>, Integer> masterList = 
      new HashMap<List<String>, Integer>();
...

ArrayList<String> tmp = (ArrayList<String>)currList.clone();
List<String> imm = Collections.unmodifiableList(tmp);
masterList.put(imm, imm.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to use an `ArrayList` as the key of a `HashMap`. Each time you change the content of the `ArrayList` (by adding or removing elements), its `hashCode` would change, so even if it's already in the `HashMap`, `get()` and `containsKey()` won't find it, and `put()` will add it again.

You only have one instance of the `ArrayList`, which you keep `put`ting in the `masterList` map, so you would have only one entry in your map if you didn't change the contents of that list all the time.

Answer (score 0):

> "previous ArrayLists are overriden with the new one I'm trying to add, but the previous value remains."

If you do not want the previous values, you might need to do something like this

BEFORE SCENARIO:

```
        final ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>();

        arrayList.add(1);
        hashmap.put(arrayList, 1);

        arrayList.add(2);
        hashmap.put(arrayList, 1);
        System.out.println(hashmap);
```

OUTPUT : {[1, 2]=1, [1, 2]=1}

AFTER SCENARIO :

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
final HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>();

arrayList.add(1);
hashmap.put(arrayList, 1);

arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrayList.add(2);
hashmap.put(arrayList, 1);

System.out.println(hashmap);
```

OUTPUT : {[1]=1, [2]=1}